# Parsing a JSON file containing \$ results in weird behavior

Tags: json, node.js, gruntjs

## The Situation:

I'm having difficulties getting a username string in a JSON file to parse into a Javascript object with the correct value. This is within a grunt task, so it is using the node.js implementation of `JSON.parse()`.

We've got a FTP username (provided by azure, and not changeable) in the format `"domain\$username"`. We need a Grunt task to be provided this username in that format for an FTP push.

## What we've tried:

I've fired up an instance of node and ran though some permutations of different levels of back slash escaping to see how to handle this.

(format: `Input` => `Parse Result`)

1. `{ "user": "domain\$username" }` => `{ user: 'domain$username' }` (seems like the \ escapes the $)
2. `{ "user": "domain\\$username" }` => `Unexpected token $` (so seems like $ needs to be escaped)
3. `{ "user": "domain\\\$username" }` => `Unexpected token $` (WHAT?!?)
4. `{ "user": "domain\\\\$username" }` => `{ user: 'domain\\$username' }` (so the backslashes got escaped, and now the $ doesn't need to be escaped?)
5. `{ "user": "domain\\\\\$username" }` => `{user: 'domain\\$username' }` (welcome to crazytown.)

## The Question:

How do we format the username in the JSON file so that node.js's parser outputs `domain\$username`?

Comment: Using 3 backslashes works just fine for me: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({user: "domain\\\$username"})).user)` outputs: `domain\$username`

Comment: that's strange, maybe you can send a special chain of characters and when you get the json remplace that to '$'. Something like "theMoneyCharacter". If you need a quick answer, cuz is a waste of procedure time. 3 '\' should work fine.

Comment: As far as I can tell $ doesnt need to be escaped, but \ does so it should actually be two backslashes \\$

Comment: are you guys doing these in your browser window or in a node instance?

Comment: So I just tried 4 slashes for the heck of it and it worked for me. `var toParse = '{"user":"domain\\\\$username"}'; console.log(JSON.parse(toParse).user);` in Node v0.12.4

Comment: The result of 5 backslashes... is that actually 2 literal backslashes in the output, or is that Node showing it in its escaped form but it's actually just one real backslash? Have a look at this: `JSON.parse('{"user": "domain\\\\\$username"}').user.split('')`

Comment: Unless node is not using the same javascript my browser (or several online tools) does, it should be pretty much the same. Otherwise it will be hard to have your same exact environment to reproduce.

Comment: If you output the length of the string, you'll eliminate any doubt of whether or not it is a display problem.

Comment: If you are manually creating the string, you will need to escape the backslash twice. `domain\\\\$username` this results in: `domain\\$username` in the json string, and then when that is parsed as JSON -> Object, it becomes `"domain\$username"` And, the browser gives all the same problems that you're having in your node env in this case.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this json string from? Whatever is creating it appears to be incorrectly handling backslashes.

Comment: `\$` is not a valid escape sequence in JSON. If you have that in your response, it's invalid JSON. If you want `\$` in the parsed result you have to write `\\$` in your JSON. If you are *generating* the JSON, use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @KevinB It's using grunt.file.read, which uses fs.readFileSync to read a .json file from the drive, and then JSON.parse to parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## So let's do a sanity check

```
> var username = 'domain\\$username'; console.log(username);
> domain\$username
```

huh...

```
> var config = { user: 'domain\\$username' }; console.log(config.user);
> domain\$username
```

Alright- so two slashes should be the ticket? But that's giving us an `unexpected token $` error.

## So let's try to get at it the other way- using JSON.stringify.

```
> var input = JSON.stringify({user:'domain\\$username'}); console.log(input);
> {"user":"domain\\$username"}
> var output = JSON.parse(input); console.log(output.user);
> domain\$username
```

But wait a second...

```
> input
> '{"user":"domain\\\\$username"}'
> output.user
> 'domain\\$username'
```

So `console.log` is actually returning the result of the escaping, not the raw value, while just evaluating the variable gives you the raw value (I guess that makes sense if you think about it).

## So the answer is to use four slashes.